# convert ubuntu 10.04 desktop edition to ubuntu 10.04 server

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

can anyone please tell me how to upgrade the desktop edition into server edition of ubuntu?

Comment: Not a programming question, so off topic here. Try asking on http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try the following in Terminal.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-server linux-image-server linux-server
```

Comment: thank you so much VSU. really you rocks.

Comment: When I was running 32-bit Ubuntu, I used to this configuration so that Ubuntu would be able to use all the 4 GB RAM that I had installed. Otherwise, the desktop edition would have recognized only up to 3 GB.

Comment: This does not remove Gnome/Unity, GUI/GDM... etc! I followed *many* guides/hot-tos, and still could not get rid of the GDM! Ended up downloading Server and reinstalling!

Comment: IAN: You probably must purge gnome-desktop and gtk. A better solution as you say is installing Server as that is cleaner. There probably is no magic command that will remove all GUI apps and associated files. I was using server kernel initially but moved to 64-bit Ubuntu as in the former Update Manager was updating a whole lot of kernels.

Answer (score 2):

The packages that you want to install is the LAMP package. You could then remove the Gnome desktop package if you want.

http://www.howtoforge.com/ubuntu_lamp_for_newbies

then run

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-desktop
```

Answer (score 2):

OK - this is a bit of an old thread, but I found a (hopefully) nicer way of getting rid of GUI programs.

From the command line, use sudo aptitude.

Inside aptitude you can select Gnome or KDE files, audio, video etc - use the _ character to mark them to be purged, then hit g to update the packages. Hopefully most of the rubbish should be removed using this method. Worked for me =)